# What is the highest frequency of alternating current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, frequency, electronics, electrical-engineering

What is the highest frequency of AC that we can possibly produce?

is there only one method of inducing AC?

for dipole antennas that can produce frequencies up to GHz, it must need an AC current, or is it?

for configurations of generators that I know, it would break into pieces if spinning up to such high RPM.

Comment: You don’t need spinning metal generators to create ac.

Comment: Electronic circuits can produce AC signals without the use of any moving parts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_oscillator

Answer (score 1):

> What is the highest frequency of AC that we can possibly produce?

Nuclear gamma rays have frequencies above $10^{20}$ hertz, and you may model their emission as a result of AC currents flowing inside atomic nuclei.

> is there only one method of inducing AC?

No, there are many.

> for dipole antennas that can produce frequencies up to GHz, it must need an AC current, or is it?

Yes.

> for configurations of generators that I know, it would break into pieces if spinning up to such high RPM.

Yes. Practical [mechanical generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexanderson_alternator) are limited to ~100 kHz. But electronics are not so limited. Even at frequencies within reach of mechanical generators, it's often more practical to use an electronic [inverter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_inverter).

Comment: Gamma rays are not alternating _current._ (AC)

Comment: @SolomonSlow But the oscillating electromagnetic moment of the nucleus that radiates a gamma ray implies that an AC current is flowing within the nucleus.